# How can I resize the iframe without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have some swf embedded in iframe but only if the page is refreshed the iframe is resized, then if I select other one then will show as all swf not only the animation the background as well. This is what I am using

```
if ( 'resizeIframe' === $('#onPlayAction').val() ) {
    var ifrEl = $('div.player-container iframe.page-iframe')[0];

    $(ifrEl).show();
    ifrEl.src = htmlPageBrowserUri;
    ifrEl.onload = function() {
      ifrEl.width = ifrEl.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
      ifrEl.height = ifrEl.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this.

1. You can change the size on every window resize

```js
$(window).on('resize', function (){

  ifrEl.width = ... ;
  ifrEl.height = ... ;

})
```

2. You can use some jQuery plugins like [iFrame Resizer](http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer)
3. You can use some nifty css tricks. Go search for `responsive iframes using css` and you will find a ton of good answers.

I hope this all helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue with your code might be thses two lines :

```
   ifrEl.src = htmlPageBrowserUri;
    ifrEl.onload = function() {
```

The problem being that the first line set s the frame address, but second line sets the onload event immediately, probably before the page has loaded ? So when the page does load, the line setting onload event has already run & so doens't get set.

I don't quite understand the text in your question (sorry!) but the code below successfully resizes an iframe - it's run 'onload' in the frame's page:

```
<body onload="setParent()">
```

In case it's relevant, the iframe itself has attributes:

```
 <iframe id="neckfinishframe"  style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden" src=".. etc">
```

In my case I'm only concerned about height. Width is 100%.

In the iFrame page, this code runs from the onload event to amend the iframe height to be whatever the height of the page is, plus a bit. This is intended to avoid showing a set of scroll bars within the iframe.

```
function setParent() {
// runs onload in iframe page
// in my case I have to run it from the frame page because I need to know the page rendered height in order to set the iframe height

var f;
try {f = parent.getElementById("neckfinishframe")} catch (e) {};
if (f != null) f.style.height=(this.document.body.scrollHeight+30)+"px";
```

}

Note - I haven't tried this cross- browser but I know it works in IE.